# Why am I not getting words, only letters?

Tags: python

I'm wanting to read a file selected by the user via input and sort out all of the words within that txt file alphabetically. The output on this specific code is only outputting all of the letters from the txt file.

- OUTPUT example:
  A
  a
  e
  l
  n
  p
- desired OUTPUT: `['apple', 'ein', 'pear', 'purple']`

```
f = open(input("What file would you like to import?"))
for word in sorted(f.read().split()):
    print(sorted(word))
```

Comment: Get rid of your second call to sort()

Comment: What do you think `sorted(words)` does? Why did you do that? You already sorted the list on the line before.

Comment: Your desired output isn't sorted at all.

Comment: I was able to remove the redundant .split call and the list is now showing the words in aplha, but I need to lowercase them now. Thank you!

Comment: Just replace `sorted(word)` with `word`.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close!  You just don't want to sort the word before you print it. You've already sorted the list:

```
f = open(input("What file would you like to import?"))
for word in sorted(f.read().split()):
    print(word)
```

Sample file contents:

```
now is the time for all good
men to come to the aid of
their country
```

Result:

```
aid
all
come
country
for
good
is
men
now
of
the
the
their
time
to
to
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `sorted(word)` then `sorted` splits your word (string) into letters and sorts them, you don't need to use sorted, just use `word` as your words are already sorted! Corrected code below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BCkIhEEX3fsXQRoVw0@5B9BmtBUfekOmgI/a@3qzobg5cDpfLh@wlX@YcJDsUxmy0YBMnL9Fn0ENb8A3iBtGNSoJGe@aEwL1@gb4CUtZWqQjX3wJl7mJO990LRFrWKD0FOEqHRA8EKUBPLlVuJ2tVLHUJNQBlaKvEYKKr6IOxrnEiMdZuCla4Uhbzce2c/5dv)

```
f = open(input("What file would you like to import?"))
for word in sorted(f.read().split()):
    print(word)
```

Input file:

```
apple purple pear ein
```

Output:

```
apple
ein
pear
purple
```

If you need to have a `list` in output, you may use next simple code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BCgIxDEX3c4rgpglIN@4E8RiuC5MywdqGNqXO6euguPo8eDy@7raVfJlziG1QlDM642be3ubO4IYjCA3iFaIfVYzRBdXEoL1@h0MFluxoWSLcfgXJ2g1Pjy0YRDmsUXpaYS8dkjwZrIC8tFS7n4gWrZIN24G8YvSVw4rkmyYxJKI5/38@)

```
f = open(input("What file would you like to import?"))
print(sorted(f.read().split()))
```

Input file:

```
apple purple pear ein
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'ein', 'pear', 'purple']
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OPs code was trying to do.

Comment: @Steve Corrected!